# VSCode not creating launch.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I'm debugging a project in VSCode using msvc. When I run the debugger, VSCode asks me to choose an environment and I choose the "C++ (Windows)" option:

[image: choose_environment]

Then it asks me to select a configuration:

[image]

I choose the "cl.exe build and debug active file". Everything runs correctly and it creates the ".vscode" folder with the "tasks.json" file in there for the next time I try and build the project. It DOES NOT create the "launch.json" so every time I want to run the debugger I have to select the configuration again. In previous projects, the "launch.json" was created with the correct configuration here:

[image]

Why is vscode not creating the "launch.json" file? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

According to the VSCode documentation on C/C++:

> When you debug with the play button or F5, the C++ extension creates a
> dynamic debug configuration on the fly.
>
> There are cases where you'd want to customize your debug
> configuration, such as specifying arguments to pass to the program at
> runtime. You can define custom debug configurations in a launch.json
> file.
>
> To create launch.json, choose Add Debug Configuration from the play
> button drop-down menu.

[Example](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/cpp/playbutton/add-debug-configuration.png)

Source:
[Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)